# Automate process when a WordPress user is registered

Tags: wordpress, calendar

I'm developing a booking service for teachers over a WordPress website and need to automate the process of creating a booking calendar for each teacher every once a teacher is registered into the Wordpress website. How can I automate that process? The teachers are registered as WordPress users and the calendar is from a free plugin name Appointment Hour Booking, I guess I need to link in some way a code that runs every once a WordPress user is created but not sure how to do that. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: first use the action user_register ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register ) to run some code when a WordPress user is created, example

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
// place code here
}
```

...in this case to create a calendar using the Appointment Hour Booking plugin you should create first a "base" calendar with the default settings and clone that calendar for each user, this code should work:

```
$base_calendar_id = 1;

$myrows = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."cpappbk_forms WHERE id=%d", $base_calendar_id) , ARRAY_A);   

unset($myrows["id"]);
$myrows["form_name"] = 'Cloned: '.$myrows["form_name"];
$myrows["cp_user_access"] = serialize(array($user_id));
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix.'cpappbk_forms', $myrows);
```

... so the complete code will be this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $base_calendar_id = 1;
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."cpappbk_forms WHERE id=%d", $base_calendar_id) , ARRAY_A);   

    unset($myrows["id"]);
    $myrows["form_name"] = 'Cloned: '.$myrows["form_name"];
    $myrows["cp_user_access"] = serialize(array($user_id));
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix.'cpappbk_forms', $myrows);
}
```

Ideally put the code into your theme’s functions.php file to avoid get it overwritten by a plugin update.

I hope this helps!